# Is there a site that lists all the best viewpoints of Lisbon?

Tags: online-resources, vantage-points, portugal, lisbon

I have a goal which is visiting all view points in Lisbon, if possible, in one day. The city has quite some points with very nice scenic views.

I know quite a few, but when I talk to people about that I keep discovering new points that are unknown to me and from the general tourist.

Is there a resource or website where I can find such list?

If this resource shows the route between them (either most beautiful or less effort) that would be a plus.
If this resource also contains viewpoints adjacent to the city or to the city like in Monsanto or from "Cristo Rei", that would also be a plus.

I leave some photos to ilustrate what I mean: [(And you can find more here)](https://www.google.pt/search?q=miradouro%20lisboa&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=NWOAU4XvNYGSOK3ggZAM&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=)

[image: Miradouro da senhora do monte]
[image: Miradouro de S. Pedro de Alcantara]
[image: Miradouro em Lisboa]
[image: Miradouro. Sta Justa]

Comment: What is wrong with a your average topographical maps?

Comment: @andra nothing, except that sometimes you may get to an high point only to discover that there is a building that blocks the view, the point is unreachable or the view is not so spectacular. It's not also true that all the best view points are in high points.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the [topographic extension of Open Street Map](http://toposm.ahlzen.com), doesn't cover Europe yet. What you could do is buy a paper-based topographic map of lisbon and either use google street view or [panoramio](http://www.panoramio.com/map/#lt=38.719884&ln=-9.139337&z=3&k=2&a=1&tab=1&pl=all) to get an impression of the view. If it is worth visiting it is  stored in panoramio.

Comment: Google Maps have have topographic maps as well.

Comment: I recently went to Lisbon and used the basic OpenStreetMap map. There is an icon for panorama spots and the indicated spots are relevant. It was on the hill of the Sao Joao castle, the very touristy area, and these were not arranged areas, just the corner of a street, the top of some stairs with a view of the city.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some sites that have a reasonable list of good viewpoints (including some in Monsanto). These are thought not "hidden surprises" like one can find sometimes on a unexpected, un-marqued, point of the city. They are "official" viewpoints, but they are all beautiful viewpoints:

- http://www.ondelisboa.com/onde-miradouros-lisboa/ // in portuguese
- http://pt.lisboando.com/miradouros/ // in portuguese
- http://www.golisbon.com/sight-seeing/viewpoints.html // in english but with no map
- http://goo.gl/oSP6wy // just a map with viewpoints inside city, with no descripption

Gathering the ones in the first link, the list would be:

1. Miradouro de Monte Agudo
2. Miradouro da Penha de França
3. Miradouro do Torel
4. Miradouro da Nossa Senhora do Monte (Graça)
5. Miradouro do Chão do Loureiro
6. Miradouro de Santo Estevão
7. Miradouro do Jardim Botto Machado
8. Miradouro da Rocha do Conde de Óbidos
9. Miradouro dos Montes Claros
10. Miradouro do Alto da Serafina
11. Miradouro do Largo das Necessidades

Answer (score 0):

If you search online you will find websites with some information. However, there are so many viewpoints in Lisbon that it would be difficult to list them all.

I believe this is not a problem, once you arrive in Lisbon you will find some great vantage points by yourself. Just explore the city and try to get to top floors, or just start walking uphill (they call it the city of 7 hills). For example, the 4 photos you just shared are all from the same area in Lisbon, but from different angles. There's hundreds of great viewpoints from that area, just don't forget to bring your camera.

Here's some hidden gems that you won't find in websites:

- 38°42'47.0"N 9°08'11.3"W - on the top floor of the Pollux store there is a small coffee shop with an amazing view
- 38°42'44.1"N 9°08'05.0"W - on the top floor of this building there is a restaurant called Zambeze with a great balcony next to it, an outstanding view. On the ground floor there is a supermarket with an elevator you can use to go up, or you can just walk around the building, although the street is quite steep.

As you can understand, you just need to explore and you will have fun. There are hundreds of small corners and streets in Lisbon that you will only find if you go there by yourself, don't rely too much on guides.

PS: There are outstanding viewpoints in Sintra, just catch the train, it's a magical place.